# Join 2 tables by matching children

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to have 2 tables (In this case it's actually 1 table in a self join) joined by their matching children.

Let me preface the purpose of this which might give a better understanding what I need:

I'm trying to look up a new order that I just got, to see if we ever had the same order, in order to find out in which box type this would be packaged. 
So i'd need the matching order to contain the same item and the same qty for the item.

Look at the tables below and note that order *1300981* has the same items as order *1303097*, how do I write this join?

Remember: I don't want the results to include any matches that do not match %100.

***[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a9f9/2)***

**[OrderMain](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a9f9/2/0)**:

```
| OrderID |  BoxId |
|---------|--------|
| 1300981 |     34 |
| 1303096 | (null) |
| 1303097 | (null) |
| 1303098 | (null) |
| 1303099 | (null) |
| 1303100 | (null) |
| 1303101 | (null) |
| 1303102 | (null) |
| 1303103 | (null) |
| 1303104 |     B1 |
| 1303105 | (null) |
| 1303106 | (null) |
| 1303107 |     48 |
| 1303108 | (null) |
| 1303109 | (null) |
| 1303110 | (null) |
| 1303111 | (null) |
| 1303112 | (null) |
| 1303113 | (null) |
| 1303114 | (null) |
| 1303115 | (null) |
| 1303116 | (null) |
| 1303117 | (null) |
```

**[Order Detail](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a9f9/2/1)**:

```
| id | OrderID |   Item | Qty |
|----|---------|--------|-----|
|  1 | 1300981 | 172263 |   3 |
|  2 | 1300981 | 171345 |   3 |
|  3 | 1300981 | 138757 |   3 |
|  4 | 1303117 | 231711 |   1 |
|  5 | 1303116 | 227835 |   1 |
|  6 | 1303115 | 244798 |   1 |
|  7 | 1303114 | 121755 |   1 |
|  8 | 1303113 | 145275 |   2 |
|  9 | 1303112 | 219554 |   1 |
| 10 | 1303111 | 179385 |   1 |
| 11 | 1303110 |   6229 |   1 |
| 12 | 1303109 | 217330 |   1 |
| 13 | 1303108 | 243596 |   1 |
| 14 | 1303107 | 246758 |   1 |
| 15 | 1303106 | 193931 |   1 |
| 16 | 1303105 | 244659 |   1 |
| 17 | 1303104 | 192548 |   1 |
| 18 | 1303103 | 228410 |   1 |
| 19 | 1303102 | 147474 |   1 |
| 20 | 1303101 | 239191 |   1 |
| 21 | 1303100 | 243594 |   1 |
| 22 | 1303099 | 232301 |   1 |
| 23 | 1303098 | 201212 |   1 |
| 24 | 1303097 | 172263 |   3 |
| 25 | 1303097 | 171345 |   3 |
| 26 | 1303097 | 138757 |   3 |
| 27 | 1303096 | 172263 |   3 |
| 28 | 1303096 | 171345 |   1 |
| 29 | 1303096 | 138757 |   3 |
| 30 | 1303095 | 172263 |   3 |
```

**Expected Results**

```
| OrderID |  BoxId |
|---------|--------|
| 1303097 |     34 |
```

Comment: Will you be supplying the OrderID you want to check?

Comment: @SQLChao, Absolutely NOT! the whole idea is to find a match by the details.

Comment: I'm ok with multiple results same as a normal join would give multiple results if there's more than one row matching the join condition

Answer (score 2):

May be a weird way to do this, but if you convert the order details to xml and compare it to other orders, you can look for matches.

```
WITH BoxOrders AS
(
    SELECT  om.[OrderId], 
            om.[BoxId],
            (SELECT Item, Qty 
             FROM orderDetails od 
             WHERE od.[OrderId] = om.[OrderId] 
             ORDER BY Item 
             FOR XML PATH('')) Details
    FROM    orderMain om
    WHERE   BoxID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT mo.OrderId, bo.BoxId 
FROM   BoxOrders bo
JOIN (
    SELECT  om.[OrderId], 
            om.[BoxId],
            (SELECT Item, Qty 
             FROM orderDetails od 
             WHERE od.[OrderId] = om.[OrderId] 
             ORDER BY Item 
             FOR XML PATH('')) Details
    FROM    orderMain om
    WHERE   BoxID IS NULL
) mo ON bo.Details = mo.Details
```

Comment: I like it.  Pretty clean/easy to read.  If BoxID is null though, it will not return even if a prior record/match exists.  But based on requirements, I don't think this would happen.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a9f9/18/0)

Here's a different approach using SQL and a few analytics.

This joins order detail to itself based on item and qty and order number < other order number and ensures the count of items in each order matches.  Thus if items match, count matches and qty matches then the order has the same items.

This returns both orders but easily enough to adjust. Using the CTE so the count materializes.  Pretty sure you can't use a having with an analytic like this.

The one major assumption I'm making is that order numbers are sequential and when you say see if an older order exists, I should only need to look at earlier order numbers when evaluating if a prior order had the same items and quantities.

I'm also assuming a 100% match means: Exact same items.  Same Quantity of items.  and SAME Item Count  so count of items for order 1 is 3 and order 2 is 3 and items and quantities match that is 100% but if order 2 had 4 items and order 1 only had 3, no match.

```
with cte as (
SELECT distinct OD1.OrderID PriorOrder, od2.orderID newOrder, OM.BoxId,
count(OD1.Item) over (partition by OD1.OrderID) OD1Cnt,
count(OD2.Item) over (partition by OD2.OrderID) OD2cnt
FROM OrderDetails OD1
INNER JOIN orderDetails OD2
 on OD1.item=OD2.item
 and od1.qty = od2.qty
 and OD1.OrderID < OD2.OrderID
LEFT JOIN ORderMain OM
 on OM.OrderID = OD1.orderID)
 Select PriorOrder, NewOrder, boxID from cte where od1cnt = od2cnt
```